# <input> has focus, but can't type in WebKit

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have run into a slight problem, and have been tyring to debug it for the past two hours. After deciding that a fresh brain might be able to assist, I decided to post here.

I know that I should post some code here for legacy purposes, but the question involves significant amounts of code, so it's easier to provide a link.

Please check out the following page: http://ben-major.co.uk/labs/phonee/#overlays. If you tap on `Prompt` (in Chrome or Mobile Safari), you are presented with a prompt box. Here's the snag:

The field has focus (see the white background, rather than the `#eee` color of the unfocused field), but when trying to type anything into the field, nothing happens, despite the field having focus. I have tried on my MBP (Chrome), iMac (Chrome), iPad + iPhone, and all have the same problem.

Has anyone run into a similar problem, as I really cannot figure out why this doesn't work. There are no event preventions on keyup or similar events...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

Remove that style, and it works. You can alter it in the reset.css file you're using. This works `-webkit-user-select: auto;` as well.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into the setTimeout function (prompt.js) ... it has a delay of 1ms? Kind of odd. I found the bug quickly... but, haven't dug deep enough to figure out what exactly the problem is. But, removing that style will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have added in `-webkit-user-select: auto` to the `input` selector, and everything is great. Thanks again. 

By the way, the 1ms timeout is used to force the animation to occur. Removing it prevents the transitioning transforms to show.

Comment: LIFESAVER! I forgot about making some sweeping type selection choices... would never have even looked for that... - thought it was a rouge div in the way.

Comment: Also, I did something closer to this:  `*:not('textarea, input') { -webkit-user-select: none; }`   (in a smaller scope ... )

Comment: after spending an entire day, @JoeJohnson saved my life

Answer (score 6):

On line 46 of reset.css you have `-webkit-user-select: none;` this doesnt allow users to select the textbox on webkit browsers!